# How to resize UIView under the tags lines count?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, tags

I'm using this framework for tags system: https://github.com/OskarZhang/TagListView

But I have an issue with the counting of tag lines to set my UIView height size.

I'm using this line for creating UIView for my tags:

```
listView = TagListView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width, height_value_here))
```

So, I need to paste in `height_value_here` a value for my height, but because of I do not know how many lines I've got, I do not know what value to paste there. The height of tags is equal to 30.

Can anyone help me with it? If you have questions, ask me in comments, please

Answer (score 1):

Hi owner of the repo here.
The frame in the initializer refers to the size of the container, not the height and width of the individual tags. If you have, let's say, 50 tags and the view container can only show 30, it will be automatically scrollable. You can adjust the size of tags inside the source code for now. I may add this feature in future update.